# How to get original google shortened URL after it's been resolved

Tags: c#

So I have a google shortened Url, and once I click on it and hit my controller, I want to be able to see what the original goo.gl url was before it got resolved. How on earth do I do this?

I've tried `Request.UrlReferrer.AboluteUri` and `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` but neither seem to work. They all simply return the resolved absolute uri. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Here's an example of the shortened URL - http://goo.gl/WSrJ6

This would then take the user (in testing at least) to localhost:81/college/events/details/23

So basically, when I hit the Details Controller, how do I get the original shortened url back?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a shortened and original url?  And the link that your are clicking on?

Comment: I've added examples now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this feels like more of a workaround but...

I don't see any way to resolve the shortened url from the goog.gl service.  However, you could send a web request to goog.gl that only uses the `HEAD` HTTP verb using the shortened url.

Then, in the response to the `HEAD` request, the `location` header will be the original url (because it will send back a redirect request 301).

You can check out the response by using [this tool](http://web-sniffer.net/).  Put in your shortened url and then choose the `HEAD` verb before posting.

Comment: Indeed. Google answers a HTTP 301 to the client, so a new request is made to the retrieved long URL.

Comment: The issue is, when I reach the controller, I don't know what the shortened URL was. The controller only knows the resolved long URL. My question is how do I know if the long url was accessed directly, or via the shortened version?

Comment: @KennySteen I don't think you can know that.  goog.gl will respond to your client with a 301 and then from your client the request will always look like the longer url.

Comment: @DavidTryon That's what I wasn't sure of. If it's not possible then I'll find some other way of distinguishing between the different urls. I just wanted to know if it was a viable option. Thanks anyway

Comment: @KennySteen Are you trying to pull analytics off the shortened url? Just curious.

Comment: I'm using it for a referral system. Tracking sales based on the original shortened URL.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer to my question as it's where we determined there is no actual answer to the question. Thanks to all who contributed.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started

You do a get request with the following url and you get a Json with the long url

https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?shortUrl=http://goo.gl/WSrJ6

Comment: Yes, this looks like the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Any normally configured browser sends the header HTTP_REFERER.

Doesn't a simple `Request.UrlReferrer` work? Or, something like `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]` or `ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]`?

That, depending on where you are coding, but the point is to grab the header from the request.

HTTP_REFERER should always contain the previous (referer) url. I don't see why you're getting the resolved url there, unless it's a second redirection (e.g. your shortener pointed to `http://server.com` and your web server is configured to redirect missing `www` to `http://www.server.com`).

HTH

Francisco

Comment: What you are suggesting returns the resolved URL. It doesn't return the original shortened URL which is what I was looking for. As I mentioned in the question, I had tried `Request.UrlReferrer` but to no end.

Comment: HTTP_REFERER should always contain the previous (referer) url. I don't see why you're getting the resolved url there, unless it's a second redirection (e.g. your shortener pointed to `http://server.com` and your web server is configured to redirect that to `http://www.server.com`).

Comment: I just added my previous comment to the answer. I don't think you should be looking at a workarround but to the reason for it. Check on what I'm saying about automatic server internal redirection.